# Glide - how to get bitmap in runnable

Tags: android, android-glide

I want to load my image into bitmap using glide but it raise the error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must call this method on a background thread
>          at com.bumptech.glide.util.Util.assertBackgroundThread(Util.java:141)
>          at com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestFutureTarget.doGet(RequestFutureTarget.java:186)
>          at com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestFutureTarget.get(RequestFutureTarget.java:108)
>          at extend.BitmapLoader.loadBitmapFromFile_Glide(BitmapLoader.java:60)

this is my code :

```
_runnable_animation = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                bm = get_bitmap();
            }
};

_handler_animation.postDelayed(_runnable_animation, _RUNNABLE_THREAD_DELAY);
```

and this is my get_bitmap() method :

```
try {
        return Glide.with(context)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .load(new File(path))
                    .submit(500, 500)
                    .get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: can you share the code of handler _handler_animation

Comment: that's all of my handler's code

Comment: review the answer below, it should solve your issue.

Comment: You should really follow the [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using below method for getting bitmap

```
 public static void loadBitmapFromServer(Context context, String url, final OnBitmapLoadedListener callback) {
        try { 
     Glide.with(context).load(url)
                            .asBitmap()
                            .priority(Priority.IMMEDIATE)
                            .listener(new RequestListener<String, Bitmap>() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                    return false;
                                }

                                @Override
                                public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, String model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                    // you can do whatever you want to do with Bitamp
                                    callback.onBitmapLoaded(resource);
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });
              } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
```

Declare interface like

```
 public interface OnBitmapLoadedListener {
        void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap resource);
    }
```

Comment: my get_bitmap() method need to return a bitmap, I can't see it in your code. please explaine more for me, I'm just a newbie. By the way, .priority(Priority.IMMEDIATE) raise "cannot resolve" error (I'm using Glide 4.0)

Answer (score 1):

@NJ answer was good enough but still if you want your method to get that work, create **background thread handler instead main thread handler**. here I have modified your code to make that work.

```
HandlerThread bgThread = new HandlerThread("BitmapLoaderThread");
bgThread.start();

// initialize your _handler_animation  like below
Handler _handler_animation = new Handler(bgThread.getLooper());

Runnable _runnable_animation = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      bm = get_bitmap();
    }
};

_handler_animation.postDelayed(_runnable_animation, _RUNNABLE_THREAD_DELAY);
```

Do cleanup as well, better place is Activity#onDestroy

```
  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    _handler_animation.getLooper().quit();
    super.onDestroy();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you started new thread like below

```
mThread = new Thread(_runnable_animation);
mThread.start();
```

Comment: I'm using Handler to start my runable
_handler_animation.postDelayed(_runnable_animation, _RUNNABLE_THREAD_DELAY);

Answer (score 0):

You should define the bitmap variable globally, like this:

```
Bitmap bitmap;

Glide.with(context).load(url)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .listener(new RequestListener<String, Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, String model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            // After getting bitmap
                            bitmap = resource
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
```